# JavaScript for loop help

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I'm new to JavaScript and programming in general (although I know some people don't consider JavaScript to be a full programming language; I think it is since it has some OOP tendencies).

I am having trouble understanding `for` loops.

I'm sorry this is so basic, so please don't condescend.

I have this script:

```
var total = 0;

for(i = 0; i < 2; total+=100)
{
document.write("The sum is " + total);
}
```

But, my browser window locks up and it doesn't write anything to the browser window.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're forgetting to increment `i`.

Comment: Oh!  So, should I be incremented like so: `i++` and then between the curly braces: `total+=100`.  In other words, move the `total+=100` into the body of the for-loop function?

Comment: Or you can increment both, separated by the comma operator. `for(... ; i++, total += 100) { ...`